# AsyncStorage Get Item

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to get AsyncStorage item at "componentDidMount", here my code

```js
componentDidMount() {

 AsyncStorage.getItem('customer_id').then((value)=> this.setState({ customer_id: value }));
        console.log(this.state.customer_id); /* doesn't work */
        console.log(`${this.state.customer_id}`); /* doesn't work */
  }
 
 
  render() {return <View><Text>Customer ID : {this.state.customer_id}</Text></View>; /* it's work */     }
```

Comment: AsyncStorage is exactly that -- async.

Comment: wow, downvote? amazing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle `AsyncStorage` - asynchronously, funny that! Anyway, you want to pass in a callback to the `getItem` method that handles the results. Try

```
componentDidMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('customer_id', (error,value) => {
        if (!error) { //If there are no errors
            //handle result
            if (result !== null) this.setState({customer_id:value}); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: my app suddently crashed .. i dont know why, but anyway thanks

Comment: because of the change?

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
   const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
     if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

[For more information you can visit official docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)

Answer (score 0):

here my answer, with modification from Ryan answers

```js
var cust_id_tmp = '';

AsyncStorage.getItem('customer_id', function(errs, result) {
  if (!errs) {
    if (result !== null) {
      //this.setState({customer_id:result}); <= we can't do this
      cust_id_tmp = result;
      console.log('customer_id : ' + result); /* it works */

    }
  }
}).then((value) => this.setState({
  cust_id: cust_id_tmp
}));
```